# CartThrob Taxes on Packages

Tags: cartthrob, ecommerce, tax

I am currently using CartThrob for my ecommerce system. We sell educational products and services, therefore the physical items that we sell are taxable while the services are not. I have added the following to a package:

- Study Book = $100.00 (taxable)
- Exam and Application = $200.00 (non-taxable)

  - Package Price = $265.00

The problem I am having is that when I add the package to the store it taxes the total Package Price, rather than just the Study Book that is taxable. Is there anyway around this? The package option seemed like the ideal solution to my problem, but it's not working when it comes to taxes.